# Beginning program trouble

Tags: c, algorithm

This program is designed to take user input (amount of money) and output the input in coins.  The program attempts to use the smallest amount of coins possible.  The program works for the most part.   When I enter a value of 2.30 for example, the out that I get is 9 quarters only.  I need help in resolving this coding issue please.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    int coins, quarter, money3, money2, pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters;

    int penny, nickel, dime, money1;

    float money;

    quarter = 25;
    dime = 10;
    nickel = 5;
    penny = 1;

    printf("How much money would you like in change?\n");
    scanf("%f", & money);

    coins = (money * 100) + .5;

    quarters = coins/quarter;
    money1 = coins % quarter;        
    dimes = money1/dime;
    money2 = coins % dime;
    nickels = money2/nickel;
    money3 = coins % nickel;
    pennies = money3/penny;

    printf("The number of quarters is %d\n", quarters);
    printf("The number of dimes is %d\n", dimes);
    printf("The number of nickels are %d\n", nickels);
    printf("The number of pennies is %d\n", pennies);
    printf("%d\n", money1);
    printf("%d\n", coins);
}
```

Comment: How many quarters do you expect?

Comment: I think he wants 9 quarters and a nickel.

Comment: Add a few more printfs for debugging. If you print `money2`, for example, I suspect you'll be surprised at what value it contains. Then look back at how it got that way and think about what you need to change.

Comment: Why `coins = (money * 100) + .5;`. I think it should be `coins = (money * 100);`.

Comment: @haccks because it's a float value so it might actually come out short. He probably wants `ceilf(money * 100);`

Comment: do not use floats for money.use int and i guess that will be cents

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the original value of `coins` to calculate `money2` and `money3`. Instead `money2` can be calculated by using `money1` and `money3` can be calculated by using `money2`. You should change

```
money2 = coins % dime;
nickels = money2/nickel;
money3 = coins % nickel;
```

to

```
money2 = money1 % dime;
nickels = money2/nickel;
money3 = money2 % nickel;
```

Now `2.30` is giving the output:

```
The number of quarters is 9
The number of dimes is 0
The number of nickels are 1
The number of pennines is 0
5
230
```

Comment: Specifically, the original code was using the *original* amount of money every time, not the amount leftover after each step.

Comment: @DennisMeng; And that's why I think he is getting wrong answer.

Comment: Agreed. You beat me to it, so I figure may as well extend this answer rather than making another answer that just rehashes the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to divide the input value into the highest value coins possible, then you can work your way through the coins in descending order of value, subtracting the amount as you go. This removes the need for some of your variables.

How about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* you don't actually need math.h for this code */    

int main()
{

  int coins, pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters;
  int quarter, nickel, dime;
  float money;

  quarter = 25;
  dime = 10;
  nickel = 5;

  printf("How much money would you like in change?\n");
  scanf("%f", & money);

  coins = (money * 100) + .5;

  quarters = coins/quarter;
  coins -= quarters * quarter;
  dimes = coins/dime;
  coins -= dimes * dime;
  nickels = coins/nickel;
  coins -= nickels * nickel;
  pennies = coins;

  printf("The number of quarters is %d\n", quarters);
  printf("The number of dimes is %d\n", dimes);
  printf("The number of nickels are %d\n", nickels);
  printf("The number of pennies is %d\n", pennies);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i like that this avoids `%`

Answer (score 1):

You should either step thru the program with a debugger and inspect the values being assigned to variables as they go or add some more printf's to output the values of the variables as they are assigned/changed. The problem you have is a simple typo, basically. I recommend you have another go at trying to solve it and if you don't figure it out for yourself, see the following ideone live demo: http://ideone.com/BsIgg0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()

{
    int coins, quarter, money3, money2, pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters;
    int penny, nickel, dime, money1;
    float money;

    quarter = 25;
    dime = 10;
    nickel = 5;
    penny = 1;

    printf("How much money would you like in change?\n");
    scanf("%f", & money);

    coins = (money * 100) + .5;

    printf("coins = %d\n", coins);

    quarters = coins/quarter;
    money1 = coins % quarter;
    printf("money1 = %d\n", money1);        
    dimes = money1/dime;
    money2 = coins % dime;
    printf("money2 = %d\n", money2);
    nickels = money2/nickel;
    money3 = coins % nickel;
    printf("money3 = %d\n", money3);
    pennies = money3/penny;

    printf("The number of quarters is %d\n", quarters);
    printf("The number of dimes is %d\n", dimes);
    printf("The number of nickels are %d\n", nickels);
    printf("The number of pennies is %d\n", pennies);
    printf("%d\n", money1);
    printf("%d\n", coins);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
quarters = coins/quarter;
money1 = coins % quarter;
dimes = money1/dime;
money2 = money1 % dime;
nickels = money2/nickel;
money3 = money2 % nickel;
pennies = money3/penny;
```